# Multi-color bar in css - ok in Firefox but not others

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I am using the following to create a 100% width multi-colored bar which runs across the page.

In Firefox its ok but all other browsers it's empty, no colors.

Here's the CSS:

```
.colorBar {
position: relative;
height: 0.5em;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left center , 
            rgb(231, 82, 57) 0%, 
            rgb(231, 82, 57) 12.5%, 
            rgb(255, 150, 28) 12.5%, 
            rgb(255, 150, 28) 25%, 
            rgb(255, 204, 39) 25%, 
            rgb(255, 204, 39) 37.5%, 
            rgb(252, 230, 47) 37.5%, 
            rgb(252, 230, 47) 50%, 
            rgb(205, 227, 91) 50%, 
            rgb(205, 227, 91) 62.5%, 
            rgb(130, 204, 51) 62.5%, 
            rgb(130, 204, 51) 75%, 
            rgb(65, 190, 206) 75%, 
            rgb(65, 190, 206) 87.5%, 
            rgb(4, 156, 219) 87.5%, 
            rgb(4, 156, 219) 100%) 
            repeat scroll 50% 0px transparent;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left center , 
            rgb(231, 82, 57) 0%, 
            rgb(231, 82, 57) 12.5%, 
            rgb(255, 150, 28) 12.5%, 
            rgb(255, 150, 28) 25%, 
            rgb(255, 204, 39) 25%, 
            rgb(255, 204, 39) 37.5%, 
            rgb(252, 230, 47) 37.5%, 
            rgb(252, 230, 47) 50%, 
            rgb(205, 227, 91) 50%, 
            rgb(205, 227, 91) 62.5%, 
            rgb(130, 204, 51) 62.5%, 
            rgb(130, 204, 51) 75%, 
            rgb(65, 190, 206) 75%, 
            rgb(65, 190, 206) 87.5%, 
            rgb(4, 156, 219) 87.5%, 
            rgb(4, 156, 219) 100%) 
            repeat scroll 50% 0px transparent;
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left center , 
            rgb(231, 82, 57) 0%, 
            rgb(231, 82, 57) 12.5%, 
            rgb(255, 150, 28) 12.5%, 
            rgb(255, 150, 28) 25%, 
            rgb(255, 204, 39) 25%, 
            rgb(255, 204, 39) 37.5%, 
            rgb(252, 230, 47) 37.5%, 
            rgb(252, 230, 47) 50%, 
            rgb(205, 227, 91) 50%, 
            rgb(205, 227, 91) 62.5%, 
            rgb(130, 204, 51) 62.5%, 
            rgb(130, 204, 51) 75%, 
            rgb(65, 190, 206) 75%, 
            rgb(65, 190, 206) 87.5%, 
            rgb(4, 156, 219) 87.5%, 
            rgb(4, 156, 219) 100%) 
            repeat scroll 50% 0px transparent;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
}
```

Called simply like: `<div class="colorBar"></div>` so question is how to make it all browser compatible

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darrensw/mNZDP/3/)

Comment: might sound trivial, but have you added the browser prefixed versions for the other browsers?

Comment: well -moz- means "Mozilla" so have you tried other prefixes?

Comment: @Harry sorry, copy failed, updated OP

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: No probs. I think the gradient syntax varies with browser prefixes. I mean the browser prefixed versions aren't same across browsers. Let me see if I can find the issue.

Comment: Just a sidenode - try with [colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) in the future, it generates the cross browser style.

Comment: For example, -webkit- doesn't seem to support the `center` in the gradient. Try using "left top" and the gradient seems to work fine. Sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mNZDP/6/). Alternately look at Nix's answer.

Comment: @Harry - many thanks, am looking into diff browser versions now, need to more fully understand

Comment: @Vucko Never seen that and v useful, thanks!

Comment: I see you have accepted Nix's answer, but just to let future readers know. `center` seems to be the problem for all cases. If you use values like `top` or `left` or `bottom` or `right`, it works fine across browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is slightly different in various browsers.

Is this closer to what you are looking for? (just added the standard, no vendor prefixes)

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg,
                rgb(231, 82, 57) 0%, 
                rgb(231, 82, 57) 12.5%, 
                rgb(255, 150, 28) 12.5%, 
                rgb(255, 150, 28) 25%, 
                rgb(255, 204, 39) 25%, 
                rgb(255, 204, 39) 37.5%, 
                rgb(252, 230, 47) 37.5%, 
                rgb(252, 230, 47) 50%, 
                rgb(205, 227, 91) 50%, 
                rgb(205, 227, 91) 62.5%, 
                rgb(130, 204, 51) 62.5%, 
                rgb(130, 204, 51) 75%, 
                rgb(65, 190, 206) 75%, 
                rgb(65, 190, 206) 87.5%, 
                rgb(4, 156, 219) 87.5%, 
                rgb(4, 156, 219) 100%) 
                repeat scroll 50% 0px transparent;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mNZDP/6/

`90deg` simply means "go from left to right". Personally I think it's easier to understand than the longer "left top, right bottom" (or whatever). If you don't provide a directional argument, it will default to a zero degree rotation – which means, it will go from top to bottom.

**A bit on vendor prefixes:**
Chrome, Opera and IE10+ use the standard. If you need to support Android, iOS6 (or lower) or Safari 6 (or lower), you need the `-webkit-` prefix.

IE has never used a prefix for gradients (people who tell you to use `-ms-` are filthy liars), so if you need to support IE9 or lower, you need some kind of fallback.

You probably won't need the `-moz-` or `-o-` prefix, except in special cases.

Beware: Older versions of Webkit (say, on Android 2.3) use a different syntax.

Check the spec for more details: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-3/

Also checkout [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/css-gradients) to see which browser supports what.